# Pattern matching different inputs same output haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function that outputs the days in a month and need to change the guards and use pattern matching. 
`

```
daysInMonth :: Int -> Int
daysInMonth m

    | m == 4 || m == 6 || m == 9 || m == 11 = 30
    | m == 2 = 28
    | m > 12 || m < 0 = error "Month does not exist"
    | m == m = 31
```

`
Can I keep the months 4, 6, 9 and 11 on the same line and how would I or do I have to put them on different lines?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. What you have works fine, although you could simplify that first guard to just `m elem [4, 6, 9, 11]` (`elem` needs to be enclosed in backticks, but I don't know how to do that here without messing up the formatting). If you want to use pattern matching instead of guards, you need to do things like `m 4 = 30`, `m 6 = 30` and so on, on separate lines. (You can end with `m _ = 31` after dealing with the special cases, to save having to do 12 separate cases.)

Comment: When you say "need", is this because you were given a homework assignment on using pattern matching? I can't think of a good reason to move away from guards otherwise.

Comment: @RobinZigmond enclose such code in double-backticks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ViewPatterns` extension to match on the result of an arbitrary function applied to the argument. (This might not be in the *spirit* of switching to pattern-matching, but I'd say it satisfies the letter of the task.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

daysInMonth :: Int -> Int
daysInMonth (\x -> x < 0 || x > 12 -> True) = error "Month does not exist"
daysInMonth ((`elem` [4, 6, 9, 11]) -> True) = 30
daysInMonth 2 = 28
daysInMonth _ = 31
```

---

This also lends itself to doing a simple lookup. (Association list incomplete to save space.)

```
daysInMonth :: Int -> Int
daysInMonth (flip lookup [(1,31), (2,28), (3,31), ...] -> Just d) = d
daysInMonth _ = error "Month does not exist"
```

Here, we apply `lookup` to get back a `Maybe Int` value, and match that against `Just d`. If the lookup succeeded (as it should for a valid month number), we return the value `d`. If `lookup` returns `Nothing`, that pattern match fails, and we try the next one, which calls `error` for any input it sees.

(Granted, this is more simply written as `daysInMonth = maybe (error "...") id . flip lookup [...]` rather than resorting to the `ViewPatterns` extension, but I though it was a nice example of how view patterns worked.)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, let me try.

If you really need to remove guards, you can match on the value of input for each case. But as you can see it will greatly reducing `readability`.

Be-careful when using pattern matching, make sure you include all possible cases.

Code below is not a good example to use, just to show it is possible to do.

```
daysInMonth :: Int -> Int

-- | m == 4 || m == 6 || m == 9 || m == 11 = 30
daysInMonth 4 = 30
daysInMonth 6 = 30
daysInMonth 9 = 30
daysInMonth 11 = 30

-- | m == 2 = 28
daysInMonth 2 = 28

-- | m > 12 || m < 0 = error "Month does not exist"
-- | m == m = 31
daysInMonth m = if (m > 12 || m < 0)
                then error "Month does not exist"
                else 31
```